# Enviar Ajax POST para outra porta?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, node.js

Estou fazendo um website com PHP/JS puro, porém preciso usar os serviços do Google Calendar API e queria usa-los com Node. Meu server node está rodando na porta 3333 e o PHP na 80. 
Tentei usar AJAX pra enviar uma POST request pro meu backend NODE mas não está funcionando.

Aqui meu código AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'localhost:3333',
    method: 'POST',
    data:{
        name: "Joao",
        idade: 25,
        peso: 30
    }, success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }, error: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    }
});
```

O console do Chrome me retorna **"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3333/api' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:70' has been blocked by CORS policy"**. Pesquisei e vi que é uma política de cross-domain mas não sei como fazer funcionar já que não posso usar uma porta diferente no AJAX.

Meu index.js do projeto Node:

```
const express = require("express");
const routes = require("./routes");
const cors = require('cors');


const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(routes);



app.listen(3333);
```

Meu arquivo routes.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const routes = express.Router();


routes.post('/', (request, response) => {
    const body = request.body;
    console.log(body);
    return response.send('Request received');
});

module.exports = routes;
```

Como faço pra enviar um post do meu website para essa porta?

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Para arrumar este problema de CORS que está vindo de seu servidor, você pode usar a biblioteca `cors`, basta seguir estes passos:

- `npm install -s cors`

Agora em seu código `node`, você irá importá-lo. Assim:

`const cors = require('cors');`

Agora, caso esteja usando `express`, faça o seguinte:

`app.use(cors())`

Você precisa colocar este código em cima de todos os outros `app.use(...)` para que este tenha um efeito sobre os próximos.

Comment: Olá, amigo! Agradeço por sua resposta e pelo tipo de aplicação que costumo desenvolver tenho certeza que sua dica será muito útil no futuro! De qualquer forma não funcionou no momento, acho que o problema é na própria pagina PHP/JS/AJAX que se quer envia a request pro servidor, então acho que o servidor não deve ser o problema. Dei uma pesquisada e normalmente é o browser que bloqueia...

Comment: Olá @MarcosOliveira :) Então, pode me mostrar o que fez no código do node?

Comment: Claro! Editei a pergunta e adicionei os códigos do servidor node.

Comment: Vc tá usando nodemon? Se não, vc atualizou o node? (Desligar e ligar novamente com as novas alterações)

Comment: Estou usando nodemon sim, amigo. Também ja tentei fechar e dar npm start dnv e nada...